# Can I easily switch from openSUSE Tumbleweed to Leap without reinstalling everything?

Tags: kde, opensuse

I used to like the idea of a rolling release distribution, but now I have moved to a location where the ISP has datacaps and I don't want to be constantly installing updates.

I want to switch to Leap but don't want to reinstall everything and reconfigure my KDE.

As an alternative, if there's a way to export all my KDE settings that'd probably be good enough.

Comment: Is waiting for the next Leap release an option?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Off course!

First create backup of your repos

```
mv /etc/zypp/repos.d/*.repo %backup_dir%
```

now you clear your repo list, then you must add leap repos

```
zypper ar -f -c http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/42.1/repo/oss/ repo-oss
zypper ar -f -c http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/leap/42.1/repo/non-oss/ repo-non-oss
zypper ar -f -c http://download.opensuse.org/update/leap/42.1/oss/ repo-update
```

... debug, source.. etc.. whatever you want.

Refresh your repos

```
zypper ref
```

And change distribution

```
zypper dup
```

Now you successfully switched to Leap

Comment: Don't do this! I just tried converting from tumbleweed to leap 15.2 and it bricked the entire system when it downgraded glibc!

Comment: Indeed, this will break when the `glibc` versions of each release differ too much, the downgrade will fail with `libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found` errors and then the system will be unsable. Be sure to take backups when attempting this.

Answer (score 2):

You *might* be able to, but don't hold your breath. Tumbleweed, as you know, is rolling release. Leap is not, as it's based on enterprise-level versioned packages. So your package set is more than likely far newer than what leap has.

My suggestion is to save your home folder and get a list of things you already have installed and do it clean.